# Which database system suits ROS better?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a project that requires storing data gathered using the diagnostics stack (ie DiagnosticStatus messages and alike) into a database in a local network.

I'm keeping an eye on http://www.ros.org/wiki/Projects/Building%20Manager which uses MongoDB but I have also seen some stacks working using PostgreSQL.

Which kind of databases are more suited to store ROS messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10198/which-database-system-suits-ros-better?/) by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2011-06-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the question of whether to use a relational database such as PostgreSQL or a nonrelational "noSQL" one such as MongoDB comes down to your data structure and access patterns.  In MongoDB, data is stored in a nested manner similar to XML documents or JSON, in contrast to tables connected by relations as in relational DBs.

I'm a developer of the Mongo interface (http://www.ros.org/wiki/mongo_roscpp), and am looking to get more use cases and feedback for it, so I'd be interested to see more about your usage scenario.  Feel free to email me directly (my username AT willowgarage.com).

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-06-15**:
I have just read that MongoDB has some serious capacity issues when running on a 32bit OS (http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations). Just keep it in mind if you are choosing a DB technology.

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2011-06-09**:
OK, if what you're storing is a ROS message, and your queries are on fields of this message (as opposed to joins, say), that's pretty easy to do.  See http://www.ros.org/wiki/warehousewg/Tutorials for an example.

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-06-08**:
The idea is that a robot is gathering continuously diagnostics information, which is stored on a rosbag inside the robot. Periodically this rosbag is sent to another comptuer which processes the bags and stores them in a database. These are useful to see common failures on the long term.